# how to change TextInputLayout error color and Text size of Error dynamically with code

Tags: java, android

This is the Code dynamically than how to change the color of error msg and text size.

```
TextInputLayout input
input = new TextInputLayout(this);
input.setTypeface(tf);
input.setLayoutParams(lparams);
input.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Soultion for this. I am doing this in my code

Firstly Make a Xml of TextInputLayout and Edittext Layout

```
<!-- Text Input Layout-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextLabelInput"
 />
```

Edittext Layout

```
<!-- Edittext Layout -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
android:textColorHint="@color/txt_color"
android:textColorHighlight="@color/txt_color"
android:textSize="21sp" />
```

In code add this with dynamic Text

```
TextInputLayout input

input = new TextInputLayout(this);
  input =(TextInputLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_inputlayout_item, null);

input.setLayoutParams(lparams);
input.setTypeface(tf);


et = new EditText(this);
et = (EditText)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_edittext_form, null);
et.setId(Integer.parseInt(item.getFieldid()));
et.setLayoutParams(lparams);
et.setHint(item.getLabel());
input.addView(et);
rl_MainLayout1.addView(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use define a custom style and add this line to your `TextInputLayout`  `app:errorTextAppearance="@style/custom_textColor_style"`

Comment: I am using this in XMl But I want this By Pragmatically in Java coding